# ng-annotate appears unable to find in its node_modules directory

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, npm

When I run `grunt ng-annotate`, like so, I get the following error:

```
$ grunt ng-annotate
Loading "ng-annotate.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'ordered-ast-traverse'
Warning: Task "ng-annotate" not found. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

So I checked in ng-annotate's directory, and there's ample evidence that ordered-ast-traverse is in there -- inside the `node_modules/` directory, no less!

```
# from project root:
$ grep -r ordered-ast-traverse
node_modules/ng-annotate/ng-annotate-main.js:const traverse = require("ordered-ast-traverse");
node_modules/ng-annotate/node_modules/ordered-ast-traverse/ordered-ast-traverse.js:// ordered-ast-traverse.js
node_modules/ng-annotate/node_modules/ordered-ast-traverse/README.md:# ordered-ast-traverse.js
node_modules/ng-annotate/node_modules/ordered-ast-traverse/package.json:  "name": "ordered-ast-traverse",
node_modules/ng-annotate/node_modules/ordered-ast-traverse/package.json:  "main": "ordered-ast-traverse.js",
node_modules/ng-annotate/node_modules/ordered-ast-traverse/package.json:    "url": "https://github.com/olov/ordered-ast-traverse.git"
node_modules/ng-annotate/node_modules/ordered-ast-traverse/package.json:  "readme": [...truncated...]
node_modules/ng-annotate/node_modules/ordered-ast-traverse/package.json:    "url": "https://github.com/olov/ordered-ast-traverse/issues"
node_modules/ng-annotate/node_modules/ordered-ast-traverse/package.json:  "_id": "ordered-ast-traverse@1.1.1",
node_modules/ng-annotate/node_modules/ordered-ast-traverse/package.json:  "_from": "ordered-ast-traverse@~1.1.1",
node_modules/ng-annotate/node_modules/ordered-ast-traverse/package.json:  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ordered-ast-traverse/-/ordered-ast-traverse-1.1.1.tgz"
node_modules/ng-annotate/scopetools.js:const traverse = require("ordered-ast-traverse");
node_modules/ng-annotate/lut.js:const traverse = require("ordered-ast-traverse");
node_modules/ng-annotate/build/es5/ng-annotate-main.js:var traverse = require("ordered-ast-traverse");
node_modules/ng-annotate/build/es5/scopetools.js:var traverse = require("ordered-ast-traverse");
node_modules/ng-annotate/build/es5/lut.js:var traverse = require("ordered-ast-traverse");
node_modules/ng-annotate/package.json:    "ordered-ast-traverse": "~1.1.1",
node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate/node_modules/ng-annotate/ng-annotate-main.js:const traverse = require("ordered-ast-traverse");
node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate/node_modules/ng-annotate/scopetools.js:const traverse = require("ordered-ast-traverse");
node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate/node_modules/ng-annotate/lut.js:const traverse = require("ordered-ast-traverse");
node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate/node_modules/ng-annotate/build/es5/ng-annotate-main.js:var traverse = require("ordered-ast-traverse");
node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate/node_modules/ng-annotate/build/es5/scopetools.js:var traverse = require("ordered-ast-traverse");
node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate/node_modules/ng-annotate/build/es5/lut.js:var traverse = require("ordered-ast-traverse");
node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate/node_modules/ng-annotate/package.json:    "ordered-ast-traverse": "~0.1.1",
```

So... What am I not getting right? Any ideas, anyone?